# Bootstrap 4-beta custom select control showing both custom and default carets

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm migrating from B4 alpha to beta, and my custom select controls are now displaying both the custom carets and the browser default carets. Trying to figure out what could be bringing back the browser defaults (in all browsers I've tested). Here's my markup:

```
<div id="memberGroup" class="form-group row">
  <label for="memberType" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Member Type</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <select class="form-control custom-select" required="required" id="memberType" name="memberType">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've removed all of my custom styles and variable overrides and still seeing both sets of carets. Any ideas?

Comment: Only seeing the custom-select carets: https://www.codeply.com/go/zmyKFRYzl8

Comment: Thanks for testing. This seems to happen once I start changing variables - either in the variables.scss file or with a separate custom.scss file (which was the method with alpha), and may have to do with how I'm compiling the sass.

Comment: Hey @J.Stanton - were you able to fix this issue? I am also having the same trouble!

Answer (score 0):

If you're compiling Bootstrap Sass and you're using Webpack, be sure to include not just `sass-loader` but also `postcss-loader` with the Autoprefixer plugin.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/webpack/#importing-styles

Autoprefixer looks through your CSS and adds vendor prefixes where needed. Without these you're likely to see UI glitches with some components.

For reference, here's the relevant excerpt from my Webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
          // Precompiling Sass requires postcss-loader with Autoprefixer
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: function() {
                return [
                  require('autoprefixer'),
                ];
              },
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This still seems to be an issue in Bootstrap 4.3.x. and yes, it has to do with vendor rules.

If you're not using an Autoprefixer then you can manually add somewhere in your scss or css the following:

```
.custom-select { -webkit-appearance: none; }
```